# How to allow CORS in hapi.js

Tags: cors, hapi.js

I'm new to `Hapi.js` and I have design one login API. I got proper payload data from postman but when I call the same API from my angular app, I didn't get data. Even in the network tab, it shows failed status.

After some RND I found the CORS issue and I have set CORS this way.

```
const server = Hapi.server({
    port: 3000,
    host: '192.168.1.13',        
    "routes": {
        "cors": {
            "origin": ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin","192.168.1.13:4200"],
            "headers": ["Accept", "Content-Type"],
            "additionalHeaders": ["X-Requested-With"]
        }
    }
});
```

I used this link for [refrence](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/11/cross-origin-resource-sharing-node-hapi-application/).

My node server is running on 3000 port and angular app on 4200.

**Error message:**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.13:3000/login' from
>   origin 'http://192.168.1.13:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Comment: You may need to set `["Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://192.168.1.13:4200"]` or `["Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:4200"]` to get it work

Comment: @marcodt89 I tried but still, it does not works for me.

Comment: Do you still have the problem even if you try to put `origin: ['*']` (any origin allowed) ?

Comment: Yes I tried that also.

Comment: @marcodt89 I have edit my post and added the error message. Please check it, It may help you.

Comment: btw are you sure that you need to add the element `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` in the array ? it should normally contain only a list a of URLs or a wildcard

Comment: @marcodt89 I don't know I just take that from ref link. :)

Comment: I wrote in the answers as it doesn't fit the comment line :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to write it like that without the `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` if did not do already. It may be the source of the issue:

```
const server = Hapi.server({
port: 3000,
host: '192.168.1.13',        
"routes": {
    "cors": {
        "origin": ["http://192.168.1.13:4200"],
        "headers": ["Accept", "Content-Type"],
        "additionalHeaders": ["X-Requested-With"]
    }
}
});
```

If even this does not work, try this just to be sure that problem is not elsewhere:

```
const server = Hapi.server({
port: 3000,
host: '192.168.1.13',        
"routes": {
    "cors": true
}
});
```

Comment: In my angular app there was a code to send headers and all, So I have comment that call code and simple send the data. Now I'm able to get data in hapi server. I accpet your answer because you have invest so much time in this issue and also this is the correct answer. :) Thanks for you help.

Comment: yes I was actually thinking whether another middleware could interfer with that... glad that you found the issue, and thanks for the accept :)